# Pass 2 params in fonction C++ header file

Tags: c++, swift, opencv

I use OpenCV for IOS and swift.

I have my header file OpencvWrapper.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <opencv2/photo.hpp>


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

+(NSString *) openCVVersionString;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and my C++ lie OpenCVWrapper.mm :

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


@implementation OpenCVWrapper

+(NSString *) openCVVersionString{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OpenCV Version %s", CV_VERSION];
}

@end
```

I would like to make fonction in my header file who have 2 params and return string like

> +(NSString *, NSString *) openCVVersionString:(NSString *)variable ;

and the function in my .mm file

How can I do that ?

thanks !!

Comment: Can you clarify? You mention you want to pass 2 params to a function but in your "like" example you "suggest" only single parameter while returning "multi-return value". The code looks like objective-c to me, not c++ but in any case this family of languages can have only a single return value. Correct version would be rather `+ (NSString *) openCVVersionString:(NSString *)variableOne :(NSString *)variableTwo;`

Comment: @PeterPajchl thank you I don't know this language with your method I'm going to use this function with one array and one image!